# Celery use wrong broker

Tags: python, django, celery

I have setup from the the [docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

celery.py file:

```
    from __future__ import absolute_import

    import os

    from celery import Celery

    from django.conf import settings

    # set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'cars.settings')

    app = Celery('cars')

    # Using a string here means the worker will not have to
    # pickle the object when using Windows.
    app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
    app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

supervisord config

```
    [program:bbay-celery]
    command = /opt/webapps/bbay/env/bin/celery worker -A cars.celery:app       ; Command to start app
    directory = /opt/webapps/bbay/
    user = bbay                                                          ; User to run as
    numprocs = 1
    stdout_logfile = /opt/webapps/bbay/logs/celery.log   ; Where to write log messages
    redirect_stderr = true                                                ; Save stderr in the same log
    environment=LANG='en_US.UTF-8',LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8',DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='cars.settings',CELERYD_CHDIR='/opt/webapps/bbay/'
    autostart = true
    autorestart = true
    startsecs = 10
```

django settings :

```
 BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

when i start worker all seems fine and correct broker url used:

```
(env)bbay@djproj:/opt/webapps/bbay$ celery -A cars.celery:app beat
    celery beat v3.1.17 (Cipater) is starting.
    __    -    ... __   -        _
    Configuration ->
        . broker -> redis://localhost:6379/0
        . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
        . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
        . db -> celerybeat-schedule
        . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
        . maxinterval -> now (0s)
```

Here is my task:

```
@shared_task
def send_mail_task(template, context, send_to):
  ....
```

Here is how i use it:

```
  send_mail_task.delay('email/confirmation_message.html', context, [user.email, ])
```

But when the task called it tried to connect to default broker ( host
'127.0.0.1:5672' ). Here is stacktrace:

```
    Stacktrace (most recent call last):

      File "django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 57, in wrapped_view
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
        return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "rest_framework/views.py", line 452, in dispatch
        response = self.handle_exception(exc)
      File "rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in dispatch
        response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "accounts/api/views.py", line 132, in post
        send_mail_task.delay('email/contact_seller.html', context, [profile.user.email, ])
      File "celery/app/task.py", line 453, in delay
        return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
      File "celery/app/task.py", line 555, in apply_async
        **dict(self._get_exec_options(), **options)
      File "celery/app/base.py", line 355, in send_task
        reply_to=reply_to or self.oid, **options
      File "celery/app/amqp.py", line 305, in publish_task
        **kwargs
      File "kombu/messaging.py", line 168, in publish
        routing_key, mandatory, immediate, exchange, declare)
      File "kombu/connection.py", line 457, in _ensured
        interval_max)
      File "kombu/connection.py", line 369, in ensure_connection
        interval_start, interval_step, interval_max, callback)
      File "kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 243, in retry_over_time
        return fun(*args, **kwargs)
      File "kombu/connection.py", line 237, in connect
        return self.connection
      File "kombu/connection.py", line 741, in connection
        self._connection = self._establish_connection()
      File "kombu/connection.py", line 696, in _establish_connection
        conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
      File "kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 112, in establish_connection
        conn = self.Connection(**opts)
      File "amqp/connection.py", line 165, in __init__
        self.transport = self.Transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
      File "amqp/connection.py", line 186, in Transport
        return create_transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
      File "amqp/transport.py", line 299, in create_transport
        return TCPTransport(host, connect_timeout)
      File "amqp/transport.py", line 95, in __init__
        raise socket.error(last_err)
```

So what is wrong and how to make celery connect to the specified broker and where in celery docs is it?

Comment: yes, its started. the celery worker starts and works fine, if redis wasnt started the worker will show error on startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that i missed celery in `__init__.py`. `__init__.py` should contain following ( from the docs ):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

Comment: I did have this, but still running with the same problem that's connecting to another broker. Any info about this?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the broker url on you config or settings file has the specified prefix as on the namespace  `app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')`
so changed my `BROKER_URL` to `CELERY_BROKER_URL`

Comment: 15 year :) I don't have this config shymore as u can guess

Comment: It helped in my case: Django 3.0.8, Redis 3.5.3, Celery 4.4.6.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the wrong broker issue was due to incorrect celery start command.

I've used **'celery beat -A=myapp'**, and broker was incorrect. Then i changed it to **'celery -A myapp beat'** and it used correct broker from settings.

Answer (score 0):

**It may cuased by kombu.**

at first my env were:
`kombu-4.6.11`
`celery-4.4.7`

celery could not get settings by config_from_object !

after changed to:
`kombu-4.0.2`
`celery-4.0.2`

problem solved!